# Вывод даты в нужном формате (сокращение)?

Tags: дата, время, php

Уже имеется дата в формате

```
2012-05-05 00:00:00
```

Как сократить, оставив только дату, а часы, минуты и секунды убрать?

Конечно можно `explode`, но может быть что-то по-эффективнее имеется, напр. через тот же `date`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как минимум три варианта могу назвать сходу:

```
// 1
$date_str = '2012-05-05 00:00:00';
echo substr($date_str, 0, strpos($date_str, ' '));

// 2
$date = new DateTime($date_str);
echo $date->Format('Y-m-d');

// 3
echo date_create($date_str)->Format('Y-m-d');
```

Мне первый не нравится, а уж вы выбирайте.

Comment: да, 3-й подошел, спасибо!

Comment: прекрасно :)

Comment: `strstr($date_str, ' ', true);` :)

Comment: @E_p спасибо. Надо бы её запомнить.

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = strtotime('2012-05-05 00:00:00');
Date('m/d/Y',$date)
```

Comment: дата **уже имеется**, мне не нужна текущая дата.

Comment: Ну я думал это просто. 

поправил.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно вывести дату без нулей то `date('Y-n-j')`